# Show image from URL, Android-app goes extremly slow

Tags: android, image, performance, url, bitmap

I am trying to show an image in my app from an URL, but when (only when) the bitmap is showed the app gets way too slow. The app goes OK, but when I load the image it goes extremly slow. Someone can help with this?

So I have a class named ImageDownload which does the download and in my Fragment I have:

```
new ImageDownload((ImageView) login_image, this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"login_image")
        .execute(path);
```

Here is my download Class:

```
public class ImageDownload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
private Context mContext;
private String filename;
ImageView bmImage;

public ImageDownload(ImageView bmImage, Context mContext, String filename) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.filename = filename;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String urldisplay = urls[0];
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();

        mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,null);
        //EDIT:

        in.close();

        // The isuue is not soved yet 

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);

}
```

}

Comment: How big is your bitmap?

Comment: hmmm if ur bitmap is big and not scaled correctly by that i mean if its orig ratio is 3:4 and u have a different aspect ration then if you scroll the screen it should be damn slow, better option is to load smaller version in memory and maintaining the aspect ration of the image

Comment: Well I don't need to scale the Image. I'm developing for tablet, and it fits in my screen. I have some EditTexts in my Activity, and it gets way too slow when the Bitmap is showed.

Comment: just for experiment, did you tried to use this image as resource? Does it show the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It works perfectly when I set the ImageBitmap from a resource un res folder. I also tried to save the downloaded Bitmap to InternalStorage and then set it like ImageBitmap but still ... the same issue.

Comment: So that means the download and the decode takes some time, which it can depending on the size of the image

Comment: But the app works perfectly until the image is showed. I know it takes time to download the image, but it just only get slow when the image is showed. I tried to save the image in the device internal storage after the download and load it from there, but still ... It gets extremely slow. I can't even write in an EditText.

Comment: if the image is large, the InputStream may consume a lot of memory, and you did not `close` it. also consider add `sampleSize` decodeOptions, maybe it helps.

Comment: you also need to close the inputstream when you are done, that is really important

Answer (score 1):

Then the problem with the size of your ImageBitmap & the RAM size of the tablet. It is taking too much of RAM on loading the ImageBitmap on RAM. You can detect this by looking into the log, how frequent `System.gc()` is getting called, as the system facing too frequent page misss than page hit, its almost like thrashing problem. I'm sure the system is calling `.gc()` so frequently and as the `System.gc()` is called in GUI thread, it is disturbing UI experience.

Comment: OK, so I think yo are right. Here's the last GC message. It shows that just 1% is free. How do I fix this? Message:GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 18K, 1% free 56205K/56624K, paused 3ms, total 3ms

Comment: The solution is either you decrese the on RAM size of bitmap i.e. scalling down the bit map very efficiently before setting it to ImageView or increse the size of Tablet's RAM, unfortunately last one is not possible :(

Comment: How is possile that showing one small bitmap, kills my whole RAM Memory? It must be somethng else ... Having in mind that the app is slowed down even when I take the image from the InternalStorage. Si just for  showing one image, I go out of RAM?

Comment: Can you please check how much free memory are there before creating Bitmap & after creating Bitmap? I've worked on so many projects where a ListView having more than 500+ different images & I've solved this problem by properly creating & destroing Bitmap instance s & also by maintaining cache of already downloaded images. Can you please post your complete code here? with layout xmls, activity & AsyncTask codes?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Google's Volley library

Answer (score 0):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). It's simple and cool.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the response. Check it out. it might help you in the future. Thank you to all of you. This works perfectly:

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-load-images-from-web-and-caching/